# after clicking {Permalink}, call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I need to bind a function to initialize a js plugin after {Permalink} is clicked so Tumblr IPA "redirects" the browser to a new page, with the post details.

How can I do so? There's not so much documentation on how {Permalink} really works, whether it's ajax or whether it has some callback function (which I would appreciate).

Of course this would try to initialize before the "new" page is loaded. I think it's ajax though.

```
        $("#{Permalink}").click(function() {
               $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
                    zoomType: 'standard',
                    lens:true,
                    preloadImages: false,
                    alwaysOn:false
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Permalink}` renders a string that is the URL to the post: http://sample.tumblr.com/post/123

For reference, Tumblr theme operators don't have anything to do with javascript. They render mainly strings.

You need to bind the actual element that is clicked:

**HTML**

```
<a href="{Permalink}" class="permalink">...</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".permalink").click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: but if you click on this post, you need the reference for the new page, so you can manipulate it's DOM. I need to run a js function in that new page after it is ready

Comment: the reference for the new page would be the href attribute? I would suggest updating your question with more specifics.